# Warning: Undefined array key 6736 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Raquetênis\wp-includes\nav-menu-template.php on line 211

Tags: php, wordpress

This error just started appearing inside my header in WordPress:

> Warning: Undefined array key 6736 in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Raquetênis\wp-includes\nav-menu-template.php on line
> 211

I'm not exactly sure when it happened. I was installing folder management plugins and doing random things. I tried deactivating all but the most essential plugins like WooCommerce, Child Theme Configurator, etc. I'm a complete noob so that's all I could try.

It appears inside:

**nav.site-navigation** > **div.primary-navigation** > **div.menu-primary-menu-container**

Comment: Error notice already shown you the line of code causing the issue (line 211 in nav-menu-template.php)

Comment: Hm. Yes. And, as I said, "I am a complete noob". I have absolutely no idea whatsoever what to do with this information

Comment: Maybe could you start by show the line in file causing the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was some weird problem with the menu that went away by itself